# Automated drilling sites with some specific problems

Tags: online-instruction

I am teaching a student basic equations.

For now, I want him to drill:

- Multiplication
- Exponentiation (by exponents 2, 3, 4 and 5)
- Substituting values in first degree equations
  (what is $(x-2)(5x+3)+3x+5$ when $x=0,1,2,3$)
- Simplifying first degree equations
  (take the same expression and convert it to the shortest 2 degree polynomial available)

For now this is my strategy for the student. This question is **not about whether this a good idea or not**, though I intend to ask that good or bad question in the future.

My question is: where can I find auto-grading drills for those skills, that I can pass to my student to do? I want the computer to say right away if he got it right or wrong.

I looked at Khan Academy, but they seem to mix too many different concepts in a basket and limit the amount of exercises. I want my student to be able to do series of 20 exercises or so, every week (until we get it right)

---

A small word of justification: My student gets the concepts involved. When I explain to him that you cannot make $3x^2+4x=7x$, he gets it. The problem is a lack of familiarity with the operations, so that some times he short-circuits the operations. That is why drills seem to be in order

Comment: I would consider going low tech and just having him use a Schaum's or Humongous book or the like.  The answers are there (some books even have the worked solutions).  Another thing:  20 exercises/week is not a lot.  It's only 4 a day (5  day week).

Answer (score 4):

If the goal of the first bullet point is to practice multiplying single-digit integers, then I have a site for that specific skill:

http://www.automatic-algebra.org/timestables.htm

That site also has basic-level drills for operations on negatives, order-of-operations, etc., but not your other bullet points.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't indicate whether you cared about paying for the website, but [IXL.com](https://www.ixl.com/math/algebra-1) provides the granularity that you're looking for. From the link provided, I'd guess you'd want to drill your student on skills B.1-B.3 (operations),  I.1-I.4 (variable expressions and equations), and perhaps V.1-V.11 (exponent properties). The website only provides 10 free problems per day, however, and it takes about 8 correct problems in a row to reach the most difficult questions in each section. Paying for access to all math questions is around $10/month.